# gotoSlide( index ) not working in sliderPro

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hey guys I am using slider-pro , the plugin can be found **[HERE](https://github.com/bqworks/slider-pro/blob/master/docs/modules.md)**.

I have created my own simple navigation for the slider carousel , like so ,

HTML:

```
 <nav class="slider-navs">
                <a href="#">one</a>
                <a href="#">two</a>
                <a href="#">three</a>
                <a href="#">four</a>
 </nav>
```

And the JS code to make the navigation work is below:

```
$('.slider-navs a').on('click' , function(){
        var idx = $(this).index();
        $( '#example3' ).sliderPro('gotoSlide' ,   $(this).index() );
        console.log(idx);
        return false;
    });
```

**[FIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/ybphbLqL/)**(The fiddle has the js and css code for slider pro and the init code for the plugin along with the custom code).

Now let me describe my problem , i have tested that the var `idx = $(this).index();` is always the correct one , so my custom JS code has nothing wrong , i have tested it  multiple time. The problem is the slides get messed up the. In the HTML i have them loaded like so:

```
<div class="sp-slides">
    <div class="sp-slide">
        <img class="sp-image" src="../src/css/images/blank.gif" 
            data-src="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image1_medium.jpg"/>

        <p class="sp-layer sp-white sp-padding"
            data-horizontal="50" data-vertical="50"
            data-show-transition="left" data-show-delay="400">
            ZERO
        </p>

    </div>

    <div class="sp-slide">
        <img class="sp-image" src="../src/css/images/blank.gif" 
            data-src="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image2_medium.jpg" />

        <p class="sp-layer sp-white sp-padding"
            data-horizontal="50" data-vertical="50"
            data-show-transition="left" data-show-delay="400">
            ONE
        </p>    

    </div>

    <div class="sp-slide">
        <img class="sp-image" src="../src/css/images/blank.gif" 
            data-src="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image3_medium.jpg" />

        <p class="sp-layer sp-white sp-padding"
            data-horizontal="50" data-vertical="50"
            data-show-transition="left" data-show-delay="400">
            TWO
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="sp-slide">
        <img class="sp-image" src="../src/css/images/blank.gif" 
            data-src="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image4_medium.jpg" />

        <p class="sp-layer sp-white sp-padding"
            data-horizontal="50" data-vertical="50"
            data-show-transition="left" data-show-delay="400">
            THREE
        </p>
    </div>

</div>
```

When i `inspect element` i see that sometimes the slides are loaded in a random order , that obviously makes the custom navigation of mine look like its faulty , I don't see the point of having a function like **[gotoslide](https://github.com/bqworks/slider-pro/blob/master/docs/api.md#gotoslide-index-)**, when the plugin is going to cause the Slides in a random order ?

Is there some Hacky intelligent trickery that i can do to overcome this bug ? or am i doing something obviously wrong ? can somebody explain ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well , actually just a second after i posted the question i realized the shuffle option is enabled:

```
        shuffle: true,
```

That needs to be turned to false.

P.S. i beleive when shuffle is turned on, `gotoSlide` should be turned off or should not work , or should just log a message in the console saying something like "when shuffle is turned on , `gotoSlide` s dysfunctional" , i've just spent 2 hours on this issue and i see no point of using `gotoslide` when shuffle is turned on !

Comment: Well, that's why people need programmers, machines on their own are (still) pretty stupid.